# convert nsbezierpath to cgpath in xamarin

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin

Does anyone know how to get a CGPath from a NSBezierPath in Xamarin c#? There is a method to do the conversion in ObjC or Swift, but I believe there might be some issue in Xamarin since I couldn't find the mutablepath class.

```
private CGPath QuartzPath(NSBezierPath nsPath){
        nint j, numElements;
        CGPath immutablePath = null;
        numElements = nsPath.ElementCount;

        if(numElements > 0){
            CGPath path = new CGPath();
            CGPoint[] points = new CGPoint[] { new CGPoint(0.0f, 0.0f),new CGPoint(0.0f, 0.0f),new CGPoint(0.0f, 0.0f) };
            bool didClosePath = true;

            for (j = 0; j < numElements; j++){
                switch (nsPath.ElementAt(j)){
                    case NSBezierPathElement.MoveTo:
                        path.MoveToPoint(points[0].X, points[0].Y);
                        break;
                    case NSBezierPathElement.LineTo:
                        path.AddLineToPoint(points[0].X, points[0].Y);
                        didClosePath = false;
                        break;
                    case NSBezierPathElement.CurveTo:
                        path.AddCurveToPoint(points[0].X, points[0].Y, points[1].X, points[1].Y, points[2].X, points[2].Y);
                        didClosePath = false;
                        break;
                    case NSBezierPathElement.ClosePath:
                        path.CloseSubpath();
                        didClosePath = true;
                        break;
                }
            }
            if(!didClosePath){
                path.CloseSubpath();
            }
            immutablePath = path.Copy();
        }
        return immutablePath;
    }
```

this is basically my translation. In the original version, "path" variable was declared as mutablepath, but I couldn't find a corresponding class in xamarin. So is it ok to just use ordinary CGPath?

Comment: why don't you show us what you've already tried and explain what specific problems you're having, rather than just ask us to solve the problem for you?  Most ObjC --> Xamarin code conversions are pretty straightforward.

Comment: @Jason Thanks very much for reminding me! Just added my code

Comment: to answer your question about CGPath, I think you're correct, but it would be easiest to just test it and see.  ObjC makes a distinction between mutable and unmutable objects that Xamarin sometimes does not.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static CGPath ToCGPath(this NSBezierPath nsPath)
{
    var cgPath = new CGPath();
    var points = null as CGPoint[];

    for (int i = 0; i < nsPath.ElementCount; i++)
    {
        var type = nsPath.ElementAt(i, out points);

        switch (type)
        {
            case NSBezierPathElement.MoveTo:
                cgPath.MoveToPoint(points[0]);
                break;

            case NSBezierPathElement.LineTo:
                cgPath.AddLineToPoint(points[0]);
                break;

            case NSBezierPathElement.CurveTo:
                cgPath.AddCurveToPoint(cp1: points[0], cp2: points[1], point: points[2]);
                break;    

            case NSBezierPathElement.ClosePath:
                cgPath.CloseSubpath();
                break;    
        }
    }

    return cgPath;
}
```